# Unable to launch PostgreSQL on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have downloaded the macOS version of PostgreSQL to my MacBook Air from [postgresql.org](/https://www.postgresql.org/download/), but I am unable to launch the downloaded program. Below is the error message I am getting:

[image]

Comment: You downloaded [Postgresql.app](https://postgresapp.com/) ?  Or something else?

Comment: I have downloaded Postgres for mac from https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/10cayz3/new_macbook_pro_cannot_open_up_fresh_install_of/

Comment: What is your exact MacBook Air model and which macOS is installed on it?

Comment: macbook air m2-ventura 13.4

Answer (score 1):

From the icon I conclude that you want to open pgAdmin.

Find pgAdmin on Finder, then go to *Get Info*, and check the box **Open with Rosseta**.

Comment: Thankyou this worked.